# Show that the number of triplets $(a_{n},b_{n})$ define $L(m,n)=\sum_{d_{1}|m,d_{2}|n,d_{1}<m,d_{2}<n}L(d_{1},d_{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

lei sequence $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\cdots,a_{m},b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}$ be natural number,and $a_{1}<a_{2}<\cdots<a_{m},b_{1}<b_{2}<\cdots<b_{n}$ if such
$$\{a_{i}+b_{j}|1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n\}=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,mn-1\}$$
  Assmue that $L(m,n)$ is  the number of triplets $(a_{n},b_{n})  $

show that：
$$L(m,n)=\sum_{d_{1}|m,d_{2}|n,d_{1}<m,d_{2}<n}L(d_{1},d_{2})$$

Comment: Sorry not sure if I understand correctly what is the number of triplets. Could you please clarify?

Comment: for example,if $a_{n}=n, n^2$, $b_{n}=n+1.n+2$,then the number of triplets $(a_{n},b_{n})$ it's $2\times2=4$

Comment: I don't understand "triplets" either. You say "triplets $(a_n,b_n)$", but $(a_n,b_n)$ is a pair, not a triplet. Your comment above is also confusing. How can $a_n = n, n^2$, when $a_n$ is defined to be a natural number (as opposed to the pair $n,n^2$)